# AWS SSD Volume pricing and IO requests

Tags: amazon-web-services, storage, cloud, ssd

I'm looking at the pricing for the new SSD storage volumes [here](http://aws.amazon.com/ebs/pricing/), and I see that there is no listed charge for **per 1 million I/O requests** like there is with magnetic volumes.

Does that mean there is no charge for reads/writes like there is with the old magnetic volumes? That doesn't make sense to me, why wouldn't there be a charge for that? Do SSD's not degrade with use like HDD's?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it needs to be addressed to AWS support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is correct, there is only the charge for storage provisioned. From the [AWS Blog](http://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-ssd-backed-elastic-block-storage/):

> General Purpose (SSD) volumes take advantage of the increasing
>   cost-effectiveness of SSD storage to offer customers 10x more IOPS,
>   1/10th the latency, and more bandwidth and consistent performance than
>   offerings based on magnetic storage. With a simple pricing structure
>   where you only pay for the storage provisioned (no need to provision
>   IOPS or to factor in the cost of I/O operations), the new volumes are
>   priced as low as $0.10/GB-month.
>
> General Purpose (SSD) volumes are designed to provide more than enough
>   performance for a broad set of workloads all at a low cost. **They
>   predictably burst up to 3,000 IOPS, and reliably deliver 3 sustained
>   IOPS for every GB of configured storage**. In other words, a 10 GB
>   volume will reliably deliver 30 IOPS and a 100 GB volume will reliably
>   deliver 300 IOPS. There are more details on the mechanics of the burst
>   model below, but most applications won't exceed their burst and actual
>   performance will usually be higher than the baseline. The volumes are
>   designed to deliver the configured level of IOPS performance with 99%
>   consistency.

In other words, the old I/O pricing model wouldn't make much sense with these new volumes. Sustained IOPS seem bound to the amount of storage on your volume. It seems preferential to likewise combine those now-related costs instead of charging you for I/O requests separately.

Comment: Ah, ok so you're saying that the per request charge was less about wear and tear and more about being a limited resource. I can see that.